# Selecting only one value in multi-select picklist?

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

Can we restrict user to select only one value from multiselect picklist in visualforce.
If yes,please let me know the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to call it as multiselect picklist then?agreed on PJC that you will have to make it normal picklists

Answer (score 3):

Use a normal picklist.

Or use `apex:selectList` and put the attribute `size` on "1" ([documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'multiselect' attribute on the apex:selectList component to control this behaviour, take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm).

> A Boolean value that specifies whether users can select more than one option as a time from this selectList. If set to true, users can select more than one option at a time. If not specified, this value defaults to false. If multiselect is true, the value attribute must be of type String[] or a List of strings. Otherwise, it must be of type String.